# Airflow scheduler with kubernetes executor fails :- Unknown error in KubernetesJobWatcher

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to set up airflow with the kubernetes executor. I have cloned airflow 1.10.6 and am building the docker image and then deploying it with kube.
The pods are running, the service airflow also starts. The webserver is working fine.
But when I check the logs for the scheduler I get the following error.

```
ERROR - Error while health checking kube watcher process. Process died for unknown reasons
INFO - Event: and now my watch begins starting at resource_version: 0
ERROR - Unknown error in KubernetesJobWatcher. Failing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/executors/kubernetes_executor.py", line 333, in run
    self.worker_uuid, self.kube_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/executors/kubernetes_executor.py", line 358, in _run
    **kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kubernetes/watch/watch.py", line 144, in stream
    for line in iter_resp_lines(resp):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kubernetes/watch/watch.py", line 48, in iter_resp_lines
    for seg in resp.read_chunked(decode_content=False):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 781, in read_chunked
    self._original_response.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 439, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.0.0.1', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Any help/pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Thats the full error output? Are you using Kubeadm, Minikube, any Cloud provider (EKS, GKE?). Did you use any tutorials?

Comment: I found out that the issue was due to the response from the Kubernetes API. I raised a Jira for the same and they have handled this issue. So now instead of the error, we get a warning.

Comment: So now with warning it's working or you are still unable to fails?

Comment: @ashutosh I am facing the same error. Can you elaborate on the fix?

Comment: @bibin please follow the jira i had raised. It has a github fix link as well.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/AIRFLOW-6040

Comment: @ashutoshsrivastava did you get this working. i am also having same issue

Comment: @VikashSingh try https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/6643 set 'timeout_seconds': 50. This is a temp fix.